# Where does this matrix rotation formula come from?

Tags: matrices

Im in a book and they use this rotation matrix formula in the picture.

[image]

Where does it come from. I know that the c in the matrix is for Cos and the s is for Sin.

Is there a proof?

Comment: What is $x$, $y$ and $z$ supposed to mean? I calculated $RR^T$ and it was not obvious to me that it should be the identity matrix.

Comment: I think x, y, and z are either 1 or 0 to show if it is rotation around that axis

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle